# Why is my function producing strings with numbers?

Tags: scala

I wrote this code using Scala 2.12.2 Java 1.8.0_121

```
import scala.util.Random
def randomString(length: Int) : String = {
   Random.alphanumeric.dropWhile(_.isDigit).take(length).mkString
}
```

when I run this

```
randomString(10)
```

I get the output

```
"UfuoB8POL5"
```

I am puzzled by this and fail to understand why did the digit like 8 and 5 make it into the final output of the function? it should have been filtered out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you should use `filterNot` instead of `dropWhile`. To demonstrate their difference on a simple example:

```
"123abc456def".dropWhile(_.isDigit) // results into "abc456def"
"123abc456def".filterNot(_.isDigit) // results into "abcdef"
```

In other words, `dropWhile` only removes a prefix which does not satisfy the predicate, while `filterNot` removes all elements which do not satisfy the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `filterNot` function

```
Random.alphanumeric.filterNot(_.isDigit).take(length).mkString
```

`dropWhile` skip elements of sequence while condition is true. Imagine you sequence is `Seq("1", "2", "a", "3")`. It will skip `"1", "2"` and return rest.

Comment: dropWhile only skips the first however many items, until it finds the first item where the evaluation is false, then it returns **all** the remaining items from that point on?

Comment: Yes, for example you could trim leading space from a string with `str.dropWhile(_.isWhitespace)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Random.alphanumeric.dropWhile(_.isDigit).take(length).mkString
```

alphanumeric means both numbers and letters will be used when generating the string. You will need to "filter" out the numbers.

should be:

```
Random.alphanumeric.filterNot(_.isDigit).take(length).mkString
```

Comment: Solution seems right, but you don't explain it. `alphanumeric` isn't the problem here - `_.dropWhile` is

Comment: I am still new at scala and this whole answering question thing.